# Replace clicked elements content and then have it returned again on second click

Tags: jquery

I'm not an expert on jQuery and all I want to do is replace the first element that I clicked that has the class `.arrow` with different content and then have the original content return again when clicked again, all while having the closest `li` tag expand and collapse which I have already figured out.

**IMPORTANT** I have multiple elements with the `.arrow` class i just want the clicked `.arrow` class affected.

Thanks for all the help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.arrow').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('li').find('ol:first').fadeToggle('slow', 'linear');
        // prevent default action
        return false;       
    }); 
});
```

Comment: replaced with what content?

Comment: special characters and some text.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.arrow').click(function(){
    $(this).text(function(_,txt) {
        return txt === 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show';
    })
    $(this).closest('li').find('ol:first').fadeToggle('slow', 'linear');
    // prevent default action
    return false;       
});
```

For the purpose of this example I am just toggling the text from `show/hide` .

If the content is dynamic then I would prefer to use HTML-5 data-* attributes to store the text that has to be displayed.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/PwnJk/1/)**

Comment: special character aren't rendered they are still in code form when I add them I want them rendered.

Comment: @RightSide: you might need unicode code points fo special chars. the generic syntax is `\u<unicode code point as 4-digit hex number>` (eg. `\u2026` for the horizontal ellipsis ).

Comment: I tried changing the .text() to .html() and now the contents wont render back.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your `.arrow` elements may contain more than plain text and that at any one time there is at most 1 `.arrow` element being swapped out:

```
var swapbuffer = <alternative_content>; // html fragment
//...

$('.arrow').click( function (eve) {
    var temp_html = swapbuffer;

    temp_html = swapbuffer;
    swapbuffer = $(this).html();
    $(this).html(temp_html);
    $(this).closest('li').find('ol:first').fadeToggle('slow', 'linear');

    // prevent default action
    eve.preventDefault;
    return false;       
});
```

you haven't specified what you mean saying 'the first `.arrow` element clicked' - do you mean the first one the event is dispatched to (code is for this scenario), or the lexically first after the element you clicked or the first of a series of clicks, or something entirely else ? hope the suggestion is already useful.

although the event handler is defined per class, the code only executes for the individual elements that receive the event - if you have nested `.arrow` elements you might wish to stop the event propagation in addition to skip the default action (the methods to use are `eve.stopPropagation`, `eve.stopImmediatePropagation`).

Comment: I mean the he first one the event is dispatched to.

Comment: @RightSide: what special char do you have problems with?

Comment: any special character

Comment: @RightSide: sorry, i'm still not sure what you mean with 'special characters': punctuation, letters with diacritics, mathematical symbols, non-latin alphabets ... the general rule applies, however, in any case: use the js syntax to denote unicode code points - can you give an example of a specific char that does not show up ?

Comment: @RightSide: e.g. try `console.log("right arrow: '\u2192'");` somewhere in your code and open the js console in your browser (ctrl+shift+j in chrome) to look at the output.